# webtest Request failed: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: performance, visualstudio, performance-testing, web-testing, ssl

I have developed some webtests in VS2017 pointing to a test site which on my local machine run and pass as expected

When running these on our test rig I get a "Request failed: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel." error on each call.

My local setup is running windows 10 with VS2017 and my test rig is running server 2008 R2 with VS2012

I have seen some threads about creating a plugin to force ssl/tls use however as this is working on my local machine I'm not sure if this is probably an issue around machine settings rather than something which should be forced in the tests.

Comment: Check that you have the time properly set on your test rig. It is also possible that the certificate that is provided by your server under test is not considered trusted due to some reason. In that case you can try to add that cert to your trusted store on test rig machine.

Comment: What sort of test load is running? What proportion of that load gets the failures? Are the failures occurring consistently throughout the test run? Do the usernames/passwords/authentication used on the test rig differ from the local machine?

Comment: The time is correct and I can hit the site via the browser however through the tests fails.
The webtests are being run individually through VS atm, not as part of a load test and they fail consistently

Comment: It looks as if the security settings (or usernames etc) are different in the two computers. Have you tried using a plugin that sets the `SecurityProtocol`?

Comment: Thanks that seems to have worked, I'm getting some other issues now but I think they're environment not security related. Out of interest do you know why this is needed on one machine but not the other, has there been changes since 2012 to make this not necessary?